# Converting to int a split string

Tags: javascript

Guys, Iknow this sounds ridiculous, but I'm only getting the rsult NaN of this...

```
tim="09:50"
time = tim.split(":");
minutes = parsefloat
```

How can I get a integer value of that?

Thks a lot!

Comment: Could you give the rest of your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var tim = "9:50";
var time = tim.split(":");
var minutes = parseInt(time[1], 10);
```

Answer (score 4):

This should do what you want:

```
var time = "09:50";
var parts = time.split(":");
var hours = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
var minutes = parseInt(parts[1], 10);
```

Comment: Be sure to use the radix argument of `parseInt`, in this particular example you will encounter a problem, `parseInt('09') == 0`.

Comment: `hours` is zero. That's why always should pass the radix in !

Answer (score 2):

```
var time = "09:50";
var timeParts = time.split(':');
var hour = parseInt(timeParts[0],10), minute = parseInt(timeParts[1],10);
// you need to specify base because JS tries to make an assumption while parsing.
```

Should do the trick. You're on right track, but parseInt/parseFloat are functions that need arguments.

Comment: same thing, `hour` is zero because of the missing radix (10) argument in `parseInt`

Answer (score 1):

```
var minutes = parseInt(time[1]);
var hours = parseInt(time[0]);
```